# How can I create a dynamically interpolated string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, string-interpolation

I'm working on creating a reusable UI component and am trying to figure out how to allow the consumer of the component to provide their own template for a particular area of the component.

I'm using typescript and am trying to utilize string interpolation to accomplish this as it seemed the most appropriate course of action.

Here is what I have so far:

```
export class Pager {
    pageNumber: number = 1;

    getButtonHtml(buttonContentTemplate?: string, isDisabled?: boolean): string {
        buttonContentTemlpate = buttonContentTemplate || '${this.pageNumber}';
        isDisabled = isDisabled || false;
        return `<button id="button-id" type="button"  ${!isDisabled ? '' : disabledAttribute}>
                    ${buttonContentTemplate}
                </button>`;
    }
}
```

I have some other methods that will update the page number based off user input/interaction, but I want it to work that when `getButtonHtml` gets called, the return value would be `<button id="button-id" type="button">1</button>`, but instead I'm getting `<button id="button-id" type="button">${this.pageNumber}</button>`.

Is there a way to get javascript to evaluate the string again, and interpolate the remaining place holders?

I've looked at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) article on this topic and think that the `String.raw` method might possibly be what I need to use, but I wasn't sure and no matter what I try, I haven't gotten it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [ES2015 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or one of many available template systems

Comment: Maybe my question isn't clear. I'm using the template literals and it is working for the disabled attribute, but the `${buttonContentTemplate}` contains a template literal as well and that isn't being evaluated. Instead of putting `1` in there(which would happen if the template got evaluated), it is putting in `${this.pageNumber}`. Is there a way to force javascript to evaluate it again and make this further replacement?

Comment: should be enclosed with `

Comment: yes I see now. Well as mentioned in the answer below, template literals aren't easily composable that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are interpreted immediately.

What you want to do is lazy load the template. So it would be best to pass in a function that returns a string.

```
export class Pager {
    pageNumber: number = 1;

    getButtonHtml(template?: () => string, isDisabled=false): string {
        template = template || function() { return this.pageNumber.toString() };
        return `<button id="button-id" type="button"  ${!isDisabled ? '' : disabledAttribute}>
                    ${template()}
                </button>`;
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can take advantage of default parameters to avoid the `||` trick.